# Can I bring prepackaged food into the Netherlands?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, food-and-drink, netherlands, local-customs

I’m going on a trip to the Netherlands and I’m wondering if I’m able to bring prepackaged food. All guidelines seem to be about fresh fruit, dairy, and meat. Specifically, I’m wondering about crackers, oatmeal, fruit snacks, those sorts of things. They would all be sealed in their original containers directly from a U.S. store, but would they be a problem?

If so, is there anything prepackaged from the U.S. I could bring? I’m not talking whole meals, but small snacks if I get hungry while I’m on my trip.

Comment: All those are readily available in the Netherlands...

Comment: @JonCuster OP can't necessarily just buy them in the Netherlands. For example, I keep kosher, and it can be difficult to find kosher food items away from home, so I might want to bring them with me when I travel so that I always have something to eat.

Comment: To add to @Esther's comment, it's also possible that the crackers and so on available in the Netherlands are not to the traveler's taste.  Sampling local products is one of the things about traveling that I enjoy, but not everyone does (including, by shallow stereotype, the Dutch).

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's in a sealed package this should be all fine.

You can double check the specific items here: https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/travel-abroad/bringing-items-netherlands